# Grouping, virtualization and scrolling in a ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

Using following code ListBox jumps to the next group during scrolling. Since one group shows more items than can fit screen, user never sees all items of the group. 
Since I have a lot of items I need viritualization.

Setting `CanContentScroll="False"` fixes the issue but then virtualization is gone and UI hangs for 20 seconds. Is there a way around this?

```
 <ListBox  
   VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
   VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ListBox.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                  <Expander.Header>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}"  />
                        ...
                     </StackPanel>
                  </Expander.Header>
                  <ItemsPresenter />
```

Comment: What version of WPF are you using. Grouping and virtualization was fixed in v4.5

Comment: @WaltRitscher I am using framework 4.5. If I remember in 3.5 there was no virtualization at all.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `ScrollUnit=Pixel` property to get smooth scrolling. The default is `ScrollUnit=Item` which causes the group to scroll as one unit.

```
<ListBox             
         VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing='True'
         VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping='True'
         VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit='Pixel'
         />
```

Comment: Ok, BTW, I meant to say "which causes the row to scroll as one unit"

Comment: Thank you for updating answer. If I set also `CanContentScroll=False` it scrolls correctly. In both cases virtualization is lost. Is there a way to fix that?